# Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 60000ms, Java consumer side issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventhub

I have a cluster that has 2 java apps connected and it is trying to connect to the azure event hub but the below error is showing up.

```
2021-06-03 12:22:29,124 ERROR [com.tat.eve.ser.EventHubConsumerSercive] (parallel-1) NONE: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 60000ms in 'flatMapMany' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

The app is not able to connect and hence cannot receive/publish the events to the event hub.
Any help on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error information search and reading more issues in github, I think this is more likely to be a dependency bug in your use.

**For more details, you can refer below issues.**

1. [[BUG] EventProcessorClient stops reading from partitions after transient (timeout?) errors and never recovers.
   #14652](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/14652)
2. [[BUG] EventProcessorClient based application hangs after "send not allowed after the sender is closed" #8341](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/8341)

You also can [raise a support ticket to confirm it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), or get a solution.